# Load specific data based on passed Id on link click in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

My goal is to build AJAX, which will show details of specific `Building` when user clicks on specific `link <a...>`

My Controller

```
    public IActionResult BuildingDetail(int id)
    {
      return PartialView("_BuildingDetailsPartial", _buildingRepository.GetById(id));
    }
```

My view

```
 @foreach (var employee in Model.employees)
 { 
  ...
   <a id="LoadBuildingDetail" href="#LoadBuildingDetail" data-assigned-id="@employee.Office.BuildingId"
   onclick="AssignButtonClicked(this)">@employee.Office.Name</a>
  ...
 }
```

Place to show Details of Building when user clicks on link. So `_BuildingDetailsPartial` will render here.

```
<div id="BuildingDetail">

</div>
```

Scripts: Im stuck here. I need to load specific `BuildingDetail` based on passed `id`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function AssignButtonClicked(buildingId) {
                var BuildingId = $(buildingId).data('assigned-id');
            }

            $("#LoadBuildingDetail").click(function () {
                $("#BuildingDetail").load("/employees/buildingdetail/", { id: AssignButtonClicked() }, );
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the logic of the click handler in jQuery. You're attempting to call a function in the `onclick` attribute of the element which won't be accessible as it's defined inside the document.ready scope.

Also, you're trying to set the `id` property of the object you send in the request to a function which has no return value.

To fix this, remove the `onclick` attribute from the HTML you generate, and just read the `data` attribute from the element directly in the jQuery event handler before you send the AJAX request. Try this:

```html
@foreach (var employee in Model.employees)
{ 
  <a class="LoadBuildingDetail" href="#LoadBuildingDetail" data-assigned-id="@employee.Office.BuildingId">@employee.Office.Name</a>
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $(".LoadBuildingDetail").click(function () {
      $("#BuildingDetail").load("/employees/buildingdetail/", { 
        id: $(this).data('assigned-id') 
      });
    });
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks you. Just wanted to add that I need to change `id="LoadBuildingDetail"` to `class="LoadBuildingDetail" ` inside `<a>` element. Because `id` is unique. So when I click whatever `link` all BuildingDetails will load, with `id` only first BuildingDetail loads.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Ah yes - I missed the duplicate Ids. I'll amend the answer to not confuse anyone who visits this in the future.